# Java - Zip output stream dynamic buffer size

Tags: java, zip, zipinputstream, zipoutputstream

I'm working on application that takes files from one zip and put them in the other, its fine with files but if there is a dir in the source zip it fail with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 1374 but got 1024 bytes)
```

I'm using the following code:

```
public static void ZipExtractToZip(File inZip, File outZip) throws IOException
{
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(inZip));
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outZip)));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    for (ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry(); ze != null; ze = zis.getNextEntry()) 
    {
        zos.putNextEntry(ze);
        for (int read = zis.read(buffer); read != -1; read = zis.read(buffer)) {
            zos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        zos.closeEntry();
    }

    zos.close();
    zis.close();
}
```

I have tried different buffer sizes but that doesn't help, I need a way to get a dynamic buffer size.
Examples and links are welcome.

**EDIT:** I changed the code to make it usable

- Liam, [Hachi Software](http://hachisoftware.com) CEO

Comment: Which line has the exception?  BTW: I would use a BufferedInputSTream as well (not that it will fix the issue)

Comment: at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.closeEntry(Unknown Source)
 at com.hachisoftware.mmi.system.Util.ZipExtractToZip(Util.java:26)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move

```
zos.closeEntry();
```

outside the inner most loop, otherwise you are assuming each entry is no more than 1024 bytes long.

I am guess your directory is the first entry to be that size.

---

BTW, You can also move

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
```

to before the outer loop so it is created only once.

Comment: Thank you, that worked, I got a tiny bit of compression(1kb) but thats ok

Comment: Also, if you do this, you only need create the buffer once, outside the outer loop.

Comment: if i was to lower the buffer size would that compress the zip more?

Comment: The stream has its own buffer which is 512 bytes by default.  It shouldn't have any effect on compression ratio, only performance.  For a normal disk stream a buffer of 8K-64K would be slightly faster, however in your case I doubt it matters (as the compression/decompression is the most expensive)